# Searching for a short story from the point of view of alien alone at an outpost

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, space

In my English class - 7 years ago - we had Isaac Asimov as topic, but this little story was not one of his.

It was about a single guy on a outpost. He tells about how normal his live is and how nice his lifestyle seems, and the end of story was that he was an alien with more than two arms.

He finds a human and says something like "and this creature has only two arms" or similar.

Can someone help me? I searched this story for my scout in a lesson of "point of view" but haven't found it on the internet so far.

Comment: Do you remember on what planet this outpost was on? That could narrow it down by quite a bit :-)

Comment: add story-recognition tag

Comment: @ mac Coop: it was in space i guess, it was a short story so nothing much to remember asside the core fact: U think the guy is a human until he mentioned that he has more than 2 Arms (or legs). btw: thanks for the correction, not an natvie english speaker as you can see ^^. @ suman roy: this tag dosnt work: it says "need 300 suggs..."

Comment: @Fulli, how old were you roughly when you read this? The tomato surprise (the kind of twist you speak of) is popular, but if we know what age it's for it gets easier.

Comment: @ mac Coop: as i said - 7 years ago we got this in english class coppied on crappy paper, so it musst at least be out of the 80´s or 70´s... Do you have a reference where i can read about this "tomatoo suprise"?

Comment: @Fulli, how old were YOU? 7 years ago doesn't really help. I mean, if you were in university english class it could be any number of authors, but if you were 12 or similar it narrows down who the author is. And yes: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TomatoSurprise

Comment: @ mac Coop: sorry did read that wrong. I was 21 at this time. In german School system i was in "fachhochschulreife"- class. Its something to go bevor the university.

Comment: @Fulli: It sounds like "fachhochschulreife" is a combination of the U.S. "Community College" and "Trade School". http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/UsefulNotes/GermanEducationSystem

Comment: @JoeL. which, funnily, is equally as gibberish to me as a Brit :P

Comment: @ joel: nice article. It is more like the gymnasium for people who were working for some years. Back to topic: it is not very likely that the Stroy is found very soon if that is all i rememer is it?

Comment: @Fulli: You never know - detailed descriptions sometimes go years without an answer. Or a vague description might be answered quickly if it happens to be read by the right person. If you remember any more details you can add them to your original question.

Comment: @Mac Cooper: It looks like everyone's educational system is a muddle. 10,000 years of civilization and we still can't agree on a way to teach our children.

Comment: @ JoeL: we cant even agree on the metrik system, or the time, or if the end of inception is a dream or not.

Comment: I also think its a dublikate, but we searched on different aspekts of the story. But nice to see that the story got rememberd by another guy only with the "in the end the Human was the Alien".

Comment: VTRO - Not a dup since target does not have an accepted answer.

Comment: @amflare - Do the other questions need to be marked as dupe of this? Or do they all ahve to have accepted answers to do so?

Comment: @JohnP - [Our policy](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7067/62201) on closing Story-IDs as duplicates is that both sides must be accepted by ther respective OP, either with a checkmark or verbally in the comments. If OP has not confirmed that an answer is correct, we don't really know its a dup.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you sure it is by Asimov? I want to let you know that is really similar to Fredric Brown's (ultra)short story "Sentry" (but that could mean nothing, given the great amount of stories in Sci Fi).

This story would be easy to find just googling "Fredric Brown Sentry", and it goes "... Such repulsive creatures they were, with only two arms and two legs, ghastly white skins and no scales". http://www.lupinworks.com/glit6756/informant/sai3/sentry.pdf

Maybe if nobody can identify the Asimov's one you could make do with this to illustrate the "point of view".

Comment: As i said - i wasnt sure if its one of Asimoves. But this ist the story i meant. No wonder i found nothing when i searched Outpost ^^ Thanks @ Deion

Comment: I wouldn't have been surprised if he (or any other author) had had a story so similar. The good thing is that you can tell if it was Brown's because it is **ultra** short story. Was it?

Comment: It is ultra short, there are you right. But: its still timeless XD

Comment: Brown was the master of the Uber Short Story with the twist ending :)